# Is there a way to update an Object inside an array in a MongoDB document using a const?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb

Assuming I have a collection called "Stores" defined as this :

```
const schema = new Schema<IStore>(
  {
    //currency: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    owner: { type: String, required: true }, //the user auth id
    phone: { type: String, required: false },
    facebook: { type: String, required: false },
    web: { type: String, required: false },
    logo: { type: String, required: false },
    promoImage: { type: String, required: false },
    ordersCount: { type: Number, required: false },
    phoneCallCount: { type: Number, required: false },
    visitCount: { type: Number, required: false },
    country: { type: String, required: true },
    commission: { type: Number, required: false },
    lastTicketNumber: { type: Number, required: false },
    //Below attribs needed for Stores List
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    photo: { type: String, required: false },
    location: { type: locationSchema, required: true },
    rating: { type: Number, required: false },
    reviewsCount: { type: Number, required: false },
    deliveryTime: { type: Number, required: false },
    deliveryZones: [{ type: deliveryZoneSchema, required: false }],
    specializedIn: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Tag', required: false }],
    pricingLevel: { type: Number, enum: PricingLevel, required: false, default: PricingLevel.MEDIUM },
    services: {
      type: storeServiceSchema,
      required: false,
      default: {
        inStore: false,
        togo: false,
        delivery: false,
        loyalty: false,
        vouchers: false,
        onlinePayment: false,
        pinCodeAccess: false,
      },
    },
    permissions: {
      type: storePermissionSchema,
      required: false,
      default: {
        loyalty: false,
        notifications: false,
        inStore: false,
        togo: false,
        delivery: false,
        publish: false,
        appOwner: false,
        website: false,
        fields: false,
        posPrint: false,
        onlinePayment: false,
      },
    },
    globalDiscount: { type: Number, required: false },
    deliveryZoneType: { type: String, enum: DeliveryZoneType, required: false, default: DeliveryZoneType.RADIUS },
    levelOneZone: { type: String, required: true },
    levelTwoZone: { type: String, required: true },
    archived: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: false },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    toJSON: {
      transform(_, ret) {
        ret.id = ret._id;
        delete ret._id;
        delete ret.__v;
      },
    },
    toObject: {
      transform(_, ret) {
        ret.id = ret._id;
        delete ret._id;
        delete ret.__v;
      },
    },
  }
);
```

the "deliveryZones" array contains Objects of this structure :

```
export const deliveryZoneSchema = new Schema<IDeliveryZone>(
{
  distanceLimit: { type: Number, required: false },
  fee: { type: Number, required: true },
  minimumPriceForDelivery: { type: Number, required: false },
  minimumPriceForFreeDelivery: { type: Number, required: false },
  deliveredBy: { type: String, required: true },
  isZoneEnabled: { type: Boolean, required: false },
  deliveryZoneType: { type: String, enum: DeliveryZoneType, required: false, default: DeliveryZoneType.RADIUS },
  path: { type: String, required: false }, //needed for zones of type 'shape'
  name: { type: String, required: false },
});
```

should I always update a single Object in this array using the below code, stating all the fields of a an DeliveryZone object instead of passing the "value" const :

[image]

Thank you for helping.